# GCP: How to do DNS Peering between 2 VPCs that use VPC Peering in the same project

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-dns

In Google Cloud Platform, how do I set up private DNS Peering between two VPCs that are connected with VPC Peering, but reside in the *same project*?

I have one project `my-project` and two VPC networks `blue` and `pink`. The two VPCs are peered.  I want VMs on `blue` to be able to reach VMs on `pink` by their internal name, such as `pink-vm.us-west1-b.c.my-project.internal`, and vice versa.

If I set up 1 private DNS Peering zone for `my-project.internal` on the `pink` network and peer it to the `blue` network, I can reach instances on `blue` by name from `pink`.  Success!  But I still cannot reach instances on `pink` from `blue`.

Now, if I set up a second DNS Peering zone on the `blue` network (also set to `my-project.internal`), nothing works anymore.  I get the following error when I try to ping:

```
me@blue-vm$ ping pink-vm.us-west1-b.c.my-project.internal
ping: pink-vm.us-west1-b.c.my-project.internal: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

It seems like the 2 reciprocal DNS Peering zones can't work together.  They are peering `blue` to `pink` and `pink` to `blue` each under the domain `my-project.internal`.  How can I make it so that my peered VPCs in the same project can resolve names in each other's network?

Answer (score 1):

There are some [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#dns_peering_limitations) to Cloud [DNS peering](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#dns-peering), such as it’s a one-way relationship and allows Google Cloud resources in the DNS consumer network (i.e., the VPC network authorized to use the peering zone) to look up records in the peering zone's namespace as if the Google Cloud resources were in the DNS producer network (i.e., the VPC network where the DNS peering zone performs lookups). However, I’ve found this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/930095/google-cloud-vpc-network-peering-dns-not-shared), where some options are mentioned as workarounds. I think option 1 (which is not very efficient, though), that is to manually create IP records in each other's host files of your two VPCs, could be helpful for you, but will probably require much manual work and maintenance.